# Formatting Web.Config File via programmatically

Tags: c#, web-config, formatting

am installing my web app via installshield. from which am calling custom dll prepared with C# to modify the attributes in web.config file.

But the thing is after successful deploying my content to inetpub the web.config file looks bit ugly and distractive.

so can we run something like CTRL+K+D like we do in visual studio to make it looks well formatted?

i mean via programmatically formatting my web.config file.

Regards,
Pavan

Comment: You are worried about indentation??? Does the customer see that file? do they care?

Comment: yes. wen i had a bug i suggested them to see the web.config file. and my client is pointing our dev team like we are not maintaining it properly. so am asking same. hope my question is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XmlTextWriter.Formatting property when writing the config. Please take a look at this post: [Formatting XML in C#](http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2009/9/9/formatting-xml-in-c.html)

This may be what you need.